# There is an error when i add to the list view on the OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

My code gives 2 errors on the "arraylist" in this line:

```
arraylist.add(.....);
```

and

```
ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(arrayList , this);
```

The error is:

> "Variable 'arrayList' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be
>   declared final"

And when I write:

```
final ArrayList<TaskBar> arrayList = new ArrayList<TaskBar>();
```

this line:

```
ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(arrayList , this);
```

gives this error:

> ToDoAdapter(ArrayList,android.content.Context) in
>   ToDoAdapter cannot be applied to (ArrayList,anonymous
>   android.view.View.OnClickListener)

```
ArrayList<TaskBar> arrayList = new ArrayList<TaskBar>();

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        arrayList.add(new TaskBar(taskED.getText().toString(),timeED.getText().toString()));
        ToDoAdapter toDoAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(arrayList , this);
        listView.setAdapter(toDoAdapter);
        timeED.setText("Time");
        taskED.setText("Task");
    }
});
```

Comment: Change `this` to `YourActivity.this`.

Comment: Btw, if you're trying to _add_ to a `ListView`'s existing dataset, you probably don't want to create a new `ToDoAdapter` there. After the `add()` call, just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ToDoAdapter` you've already set on the `ListView`.